# ASP.Net: Do I need to add javascript source of _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml to _layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net 5 project I have a file named `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` by default:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jquery && window.jquery.validator">
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jquery && window.jquery.validator && window.jquery.validator.unobtrusive">
    </script>
</environment>
```

But when I need to use jquery validation, I have to add:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

below part of `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<environment names="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/js/bootstrap-touch-carousel.js">
           I HAVE TO ADD SCRIPT FOR JQUERY VALIDATION HERE
            </script>
        </environment>
```

What is the purpose of `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`?
How is this file used in the project?
Please give me reference how to use this file?

Comment: unobtrusive needs to be added below your validation code

Comment: i am sorry, i am just beginner. i dont understand what you said

Comment: the reason for you to add it again (to get it to work) is because it needs to be placed below your validation code in the html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1) are meant to be used inside other views. You would not normally add the validation scripts to the `_layout.cshtml` since that (`_layout.cshtm`) is used on every page.

However, if you have a view where you need to use these scripts you just add the partial view inside the `.cshtml` file of your view like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

If you created a standard web project with identity using VS 2015 then you can see an example of this usage in Views/Account/Register.cshtml

Comment: I would have given you additional up votes for mentioning the Identity reference as an example in context, good answer.

Comment: While this answer is upvoted and accepted, it does not explain why validation scripts should **not** be added to `_Layout.cshtml`. `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` exists to reference validation scripts but the same validation scripts can be references from `_Layout.cshtml` just as well. What is the rationale/benefit of separating them out to `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`?

Comment: @Mike, it will benefit you of not having to load the validation scripts to pages that don't need them

Answer (score 4):

For example: you have a form with one of the field "Required" validation. You submit the form.
Case 1 : when _ValidationScriptsPartial is NOT used in the cshtml page

The validation will happen but it will check if ModelState is valid or not, everytime you submit the form.

Case 2 : when _ValidationScriptsPartial is NOT used in the cshtml page
The validation will happen but it will be a client side validation and it will not perform any of the tasks in the controller or relevant method, until and unless you resolve all validation issues.

To use the file in a cshtml page,

```
@section Scripts
  {
     <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
  }
```